# 403 forbidden in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-10

I user Laravel 10.1.5 and Nova 4.22.1
When in .env APP_ENV=local all ok
But when APP_ENV=production I see error 403 on my admin/login page

I try to write

```
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
                'myemail'
            ]);
        });
```

in NovaServiceProvider.php but nothigt

How I can fix it for production?

Comment: change 'myemail' to the email of the user which should have access, or add your own logic here

Comment: of course there are real email, but I still see 403 page instead of login page

Comment: If you remove return and return just true, does it work?

Comment: no, still 403 error

Comment: Then i don't think code you provided is enough to determine the issue. Where did you put Gate::define?

Comment: app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php

Comment: protected function gate()

Comment: Wait, if it's 403 on login page, then issue is definitely not in the Nova gate. You should be able to access Nova login if you're not authenticated. Try to check if there is custom middleware blocking access or something in your own code

Comment: oh, I use laravel permission and problem in it. But I still do not know how to fix it(

Answer (score 0):

If you want allow all users to access dashboard return true in mentioned Gate.

```
Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

To limit access to your authenticated user, provide email below

```
Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
    return [
        'user@email.com',
    ];
});
```